# Visual C++ Menu Bar: Change Color and Font Size, No MFC

Tags: visual-c++, menubar

I'd like to change the background color and font size on a Menu Bar (File, Edit, Tools) in C++ without MFC.

I've Googled around, butcan't find a simple way to do this without MFC.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for MFT_OWNERDRAW. There are number of examples in the Internet with owner draw menu without MFC (e.g. http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/23059-owner-drawn-menus.html).